# Equivalent to toString() in Eclipse for GDB debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

In Eclipse I can override the toString() method of an Object to pretty print it.  This is especially useful because during a debug sessions as I can click on a variable and see the object in a human readable form.

Is there any kind of equivalent for C++ during a gdb session.  I'm also open to any IDEs that can emulate this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gdb, print command prints the contents of the variable. If you are using any IDE for C++, eg. Netbeans, Eclipse, VC++ then pointing on the variable shows the content.

EDIT: See if the below code is what you are looking for.

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#define magic_string(a) #a

template<typename T>
class Object_C
{
private:
    virtual string toString_Impl()
    {
        return magic_string(T);
    }

public:
    Object_C(void)
    {
    }
    virtual ~Object_C(void)
    {
    }
    string toString()
    {
        return toString_Impl();
    }
};

class Base_C :
    public Object_C<Base_C>
{
private:
    string toString_Impl()
    {
        char str[80] = "";
        sprintf_s(str, 79, "Base.x:%d\n", x_);
        return string(str);     
    }
private:
    int x_;

public:
    Base_C(int x = 0) : x_(x) { }
    ~Base_C(void);
};

void ToStringDemo()
{
    Base_C base;
    cout << base.toString() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify, I want to write my own print function for each variable type to print it in a way that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand how your code example relates to the original question. Does the gdb print function look for a method called toString?

Comment: Just tried it with codeblock's mingw compiler and it doesn't work for me...but then again this compiler doesn't support python pretty printers either..might work with mingw-w64 (Really wish the C++ standard people would get their act together and define ToString() as a standard object method for debuggers to print watch window objects...  java and C# have had that feature forever...)

Answer (score 0):

using visual Studio C++ instead?

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {count}")]  
class MyHashtable  
{  
    public int count = 4;  
}  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes
```

Comment: That's for C# not for C++ !